# Android emulator screen freeze

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen

I've installed android sdk  which I'm using on eclipse. When i run my application I have the following log:

```
[2011-11-02 15:46:43 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-11-02 15:46:43 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-02 15:46:43 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid   activity launch
[2011-11-02 15:46:43 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD1' is     available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-02 15:47:15 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-02 15:47:15 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-11-02 15:49:53 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2011-11-02 15:49:55 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity  com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device emulator-5554
```

And the emulator freezes at 'Andoird' screen. I've tried increasing ram and cd size but same result. I've also tried creating new avds, restarting eclipse but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?
I'm using th efollowing code to create my first app:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```

I'm working with windows 7.

Comment: might be useful to post your code. Also your hardware might be too old. We really need more information. like OS, Hardware, code, etc.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I've edited my question with more details.

Comment: what does the frozen screen say on it? Just android?

Comment: How long time have you waited? The emulator takes really long time to start the first time.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato the first time I gave up after 15 mins but now I've been waiting for like 30 mins.

Comment: hmm. I remember I had an issue with this when i first got started with android. I am trying to recall... It had something to do with maybe my java version.. Or maybe how I was running the script. Try compiling it and then running instead of just clicking run.

Comment: can we show a TextView without and layout? try adb kill-server and adb start-server in terminal.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I copied this code from the android site. And frankly I've just started android dev so don't know much about it.

Comment: Try starting the AVD by itself, see if it loads without deploying the app.

Comment: @Andrei I've started the avd alone and it runs and shows the 'Android' screen and freezes there.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I've tried adb kill\start and now I'm waiting

Comment: hay anil is that your Emulator freez or U can able to navigate the screens?.

Comment: @PadmaKumar it freezes and I can't do anything with it

Comment: hay anil delete the AVD1 and create new avd and check it once. whats your system configuration?. http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Comment: @PadmaKumar thx a lot for your help I just tried it on my new pc and it workd! turns out it really was because of my hardware.

Comment: I am facing emulator problem for my tablet versions. its dead slow even I had good config. :-)

Comment: @PadmaKumar It's really not easy for beginners to understand the problems

Answer (score 0):

Now please Edit your ADV in Give size like 2000Mb.

And make sure you give only those condition that it required.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to the emulator locking itself. 
Try pressing **F7**(Power button) key on the emulator.